# align bullets and center text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The text is off centered and the bullets overlap the text.  The top li is centered in the middle of the page.  the 2nd li is aligned to the left. the 3rd li is aligned to the right. and all of them have the bullet overlapping the text.

```
    <div class="container counter-container">
<ol>
    <div class="media-container-row">
        <div class="mbr-text counter-container col-12-md mbr-fonts-style display-4">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                        <li><span class="a"><strong>COMMUNITY</strong> - Bringing schools and communities together for a common cause.</span></li>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media-container-row">   
        <div class="mbr-text counter-container col-md-12 mbr-fonts-style display-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                        <span class="b"><li><strong>EASY AND SIMPLE</strong> - Coaches, Create a Schedule. &nbsp;Fans, sponsor your team.</li></span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="media-container-row">
        <div class=" counter-container col-12-md mbr-fonts-style display-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                        <span class="c"><li><strong><br><center>FUN</strong> - Encourages fans to show up and players to try harder!</li></span>

                </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you have isn't even valid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using bootstrap, so just use the bootstrap classes to set up your lists:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all your `<li>` tags outside the spans on the second and third rows.

Also, remove the `<br>` tag before your third list item.

If that doesn't fully help, could you post the CSS that accompanies this? Specifically the a,b, and c classes?